# "+1" gives me different result than "+ 1" in ruby?

Tags: ruby

```rb
[6] pry(main)> [1,2,3].min +1
=> [1]
[7] pry(main)> [1,2,3].min + 1
=> 2
```

I'm blown away. it must be something to do with the `min` function i suppose? because `max` has the same issue but not `sum`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whitespace matters in Ruby, at least sometimes.

If you say `x + 1` then Ruby interprets the `+` as the binary addition operator so it is seen as a method call like `x.+(1)`.

If you say `x +1` then Ruby interprets the `+` as the unary plus operator (AKA [`#+@`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Numeric.html#method-i-2B-40)) and the space as a method call so the expression as a whole is seen as `x(+1)` or more explicitly `x(1.+@())`.

An expression like `x ・ y` (for some operator `・`) can be interpreted in different ways as method-calling-parentheses are (sometimes) optional. It can be seen as `x(・ y)` or `x() ・ y` and Ruby chooses the latter. When there is no second space (i.e. `x ・y`) then Ruby sees it as `x(・y)`. Things are further complicated because `x` could be a local variable or a method call. Optional parentheses and whitespace introduces some ambiguity for humans but not for Ruby.

So adding missing/optional parentheses to `[1,2,3].min +1` gives us:

```
[1,2,3].min(+1)
```

and you're calling [`Array#min`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-min) with an argument of `1` and that will:

> With Integer argument `n` and no block, returns a new Array with at most n elements, in ascending order per method `<=>`:

Hence the `[1]` result.

Adding parentheses to `[1,2,3].min + 1` gives us:

```
[1,2,3].min() + 1
```

which is `1 + 1` or `2`.

Comment: Note that whitespace only matters when you don't use explicit parenthesis and force Ruby to guess.  `[1,2,3].min(+       1)` is identical to `.min(+1)`..

Comment: @meagar True, I added some notes about that.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby's [`Array::min`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-min) takes an optional argument `n`, which returns the smallest `n` items as an array.  When you place a space to the left of the `+` but no space to the right, it's interpreting that to mean you want a unary positive 1 as the optional argument so you get `[1]`.  Having spaces on both sides of the `+` or neither side will be parsed as a desire to add one to the result of `min`.

```ruby
[10,11,12].min       # => 10
[10,11,12].min(+1)   # => [10]
[10,11,12].min(+2)   # => [10, 11]
[10,11,12].min +2    # => [10, 11]  since parentheses are often optional in Ruby
[10,11,12].min+1     # => 11  without spaces, interpreted as addition rather than unary +
[10,11,12].min + 1   # => 11  spaces on both sides, also interpreted as addition
```